# Using MailKit's Smtpclient to send,subjectEncoding is weird in the source of received email.

Tags: sendgrid, smtpclient, mailkit, mimekit

I tried to encode them to iso-2022-jp correctly,but the only subject is slightly unexpected.
Here's the result.

```
From: =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCJ**************==?= <sender@example.com>
To: =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCS****************==?= <receiver@example.com>
Subject: =?iso-2022-jp?b?GyRCQmpMPhsoQjobJEIlRiU5JUgbKEI=?=
```

As you see above,lower case "b" is only seen in Subject even though I encoded the others in the same way.
I found out that it's automatically converted to b right after the method smtp.Send(msg);
b isn't commonly seen.I need to fix it to B.

Below is like what I tried to do.

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    //Connection
    .
    .
    .

    //Set from,to,subject,body...
    .
    .
    msg.Subject = EncodeMailHeader("題名:テスト");

    .
    .

    smtp.Send(msg);

}
// Convert to "=?iso-2022-jp?B?<encodedstring>?="
private static string EncodeMailHeader(string val)
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(JIS_Code);
        string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetBytes(val));
        return string.Format("=?{0}?B?{1}?=", enc.HeaderName, strBase64);
}
```

Subject property of "msg" is "=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCQmpMPhsoQjobJEIlRiU5JUgbKEI=?=" at the point of debugging smtp.Send(msg);.
I don't know why it will change after this.

I need someone to help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both `b` and `B` mean the same thing (base64 encoded). The case of the value does not matter. You are stressing yourself out over nothing.

Comment: @jstedfast   Thanks for reply.I kind of find it no problem. 
But I wasn't sure if it doesn't matter for any different clients.
As I said, B is commonly seen.So I thought it could be negative in some environment.I'd like to make sure why it changes.Presumably,any particular reason for this?